# Handler testing in App Engine fails: webtest import errors

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-testing

I can't make any sense of this error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_webtest (unittest2.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: test_webtest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unittest2/loader.py", line 260, in _find_tests
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unittest2/loader.py", line 238, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/chris/Documents/gae/tasker/test/test_webtest.py", line 4, in <module>
    import webtest
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webtest/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from webtest.app import TestApp
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webtest/app.py", line 65, in <module>
    class TestRequest(webob.BaseRequest):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BaseRequest'
```

The situation is:

- I'm trying to set up handler unit tests for my App Engine app.
- I'm following [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting#Setting_Up_a_Testing_Framework) for a unit test framework, including the
  bash script at the bottom of the page, verbatim.
- I'm running tests from the terminal with this command:

  `./run_tests.py /usr/local/google_appengine test/`
- I'm using [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/handlertesting) for structuring my handler tests. But it never gets past the imports. All I have to do is this in `test/test_webtest.py` to generate the error:

  ```
  import webtest
  ```
- I have webtest installed:

  ```
  $ pip install WebTest
  Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): WebTest in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
  Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from WebTest)
  Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): WebOb>=1.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from WebTest)
  Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): waitress in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from WebTest)
  Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): beautifulsoup4 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from WebTest)
  Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): distribute in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg (from waitress->WebTest)
  ```
- I am running all my tests at once, including older ones that pass with no errors. But importing `webtest` into any of them generates the error at the top. Why?

Comment: I don't have time to read the tutorial links but I use nose and nose-gae for testing with webtest and they work great.

Comment: Kekito: per the known bug described below, I'm surprised you have things working smoothly, and I'd like to copy your magic. Did you consciously work around this error? Are you doing something different than I am?

Comment: You're likely using an older version of the GAE SDK.  1.7.5 and earlier had this problem.  The latest as of now (1.8.8) should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a silly problem with my different python environments.

The `pip` and `python` in my path were linked to `/user/local/bin/python`. That's where webtest was, in fact, installed.

The code I had copied from the tutorial, however, had this hashbang: `#!/usr/bin/python` so when I ran it with `./run_tests.py`, it ran in the environment where webtest *wasn't* installed.

Running either `python ./run_tests.py` or changing the hashbang to `#!/user/local/bin/python` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using webtest with GAE and it is working for me.  I'll try to identify differences between my setup and yours to see if that helps you:

- I'm using `unittest` and not `unittest2`.
- I'm not using a script like your `run_tests.py`.  I just call it from the command line like this: `nosetests --with-gae`